# SharePoint Testing environment

Tags: hosting-environment

We currently imaged the SharePoint production environment to a new Virtual machine, the problem is that we only imaged the SharePoint Server without the MSSQL server that was attached to SharePoint in production, Is it possible to create the new database to match the current SharePoint structure in the VM? any help please?

Thanks in advance